# CONCAT function not working in postgres 10

Tags: postgresql

```
select CONCAT(name, desc) from table;
```

gives the below error

> ```
>  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "desc"
>  LINE 1: select CONCAT(name, desc) from theme;
>                             ^
>  SQL state: 42601
>  Character: 21
> ```

the same query works on sqlserver,hana and oracle? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved keyword, you have to quote it:

```
select CONCAT(name, "desc") 
from the_table
```

If you pay close attention to the `^` in the error message it points exactly to the `desc` part indicating that this is the problem, not the `concat()` function.